# need to include one file or another based on visitor country

Tags: php, country

Visitors from either of 3 countries - New Zealand, Fiji or India - need a different content page respectively.  The site is written in PHP, the content is in HTML files ready to be included.... I'm a newb; please be patient!!

Comment: What about people from none of those three countries?  How do you know which country they are from - have they told you, or do you have to guess?

Comment: You can guess at a user's location based on client IP, but you can't know for sure.  Some users are behind foreign proxies.  Go ahead and use a geolocation API, but allow the user to override it if your API returns the wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to use Google's AJAX API loader to get a rough estimate of the user's location. Roughly:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Note that you should have some sanity checks here, and maybe use an onLoad
// event of some kind
alert(google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country);

</script>
```

You could have the user start at a page that would then use JavaScript to redirect them to the appropriate location. If you're using any popular JavaScript libraries, you may already be using this loader (and if not, you should consider loading your libraries through it).

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation

Comment: Test the country value and use that to redirect the browser to the appropriate location. Like Frank Farmer said, though, you should consider giving the user some way to override the automatic choice.

Answer (score 0):

- Get the visitor's `IP`
- Map the `IP` to its `location`
- Do a conditional `include` based on the
  location

Comment: if in neither of these countries the default content will apply but its not so likely anyone else will find the site really, its a indian church with office in those 3 countries