# Display content based on user country with Php

Tags: php

Is there a way that i could display different content based on user country lets say
my page is **Google.com** this page is for **U.S** people then if a person from **Canada** goes to **Google.com** he gets a different index page or something like **Google.com/CA** i get traffic from almost all the countries so i have to do this for each country and i been struggling to make this happen to my traffic, if someone could help i will thank him alot. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [need to include one file or another based on visitor country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687801/need-to-include-one-file-or-another-based-on-visitor-country)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I show different content to website visitors from a specific country?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088552/how-can-i-show-different-content-to-website-visitors-from-a-specific-country-in-p)

Comment: and possibly some more in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=content+by+country+php

Comment: I would like to make a question: Are the different content to be choosen based on the country of the originating ip or just by user preferred language?

Comment: Is your question more about localization, that is, are you looking for strategies to actually serve different content format (i.e. different currency, translations, different date and time format)?  or is it more about detecting where the user comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use their IP and an IP table (publicly available (http://goo.gl/oeAu7)) to work out where they are from, then do:

`if ($county = "UK") {
// Code for UK here
} elseif ($county = "USA") {
// Code for USA here
}`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the initial country content based on IP, but also give users the option of choosing their country too, as sometimes if a user is on a VPN it can route through a different country and they'd get the wrong content. It would be very annoying for the user if they could do nothing about this.

Once they've chosen their country, store it in a cookie and use the cookie value rather than IP next time they visit.

Comment: Ummm well i have new people every time like lets say each day i have around 2,000 to 4,000 new visitors but a cookie ain't like an option since i want this to happen as new user's come they get the content from their country and not having them to chose their country.

Comment: The point is that choosing country by IP is not 100% reliable, so once you've chosen the country by IP, you still should give users the option of switching to see the content for another country.

Answer (score 0):

IP's are probably the way to go here, but just to throw in my dime (Two cents seems kind of cheap to me):
Most browsers will send out an Accept-Language header with their requests that specify what language(s) their users would like the returned content to be in. A lot of these languages codes are coupled with a country code (so en-US, en-gb, or de-DE). You can find these codes in `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`. However, multiple languages may be listed along with language quality values (which are pointless, just saying). To overcome this I suggest a solution that looks for a country code and matches it with the appropriate location. If no suitable location can be found, the IP's country is used instead:

```
<?php
function getCountry() {
    $countries = array( 'us' => 'United States' ); //etc.
    //Let's first try the Accept-Language header
    $languages = explode( ',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] );
    foreach( $languages as $lang ) {
        $lang = array_shift( explode( ';', $lang ) );
        if( strpos( $lang, '-' ) != false ) {
            $country = strtolower( trim( array_pop( explode( '-', $lang ) ) ) );
            if( isset( $countries[$country] ) ) {
                return( $countries[$country] );
            }
        }
    }
    //Fall back to IP's location
    if( isset( $_SERVER['X-Forwarded-For'] ) ) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['X-Forwarded-For']; //Circumvent some basic proxies
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    geoip_country_name_by_name( $ip ); //Assuming you have GeoIP
}

echo getCountry();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ip to country database on your MYSQL data base and run a script (PHP) to get the ip from the user and select the country from database.
You can download a ip to country databaseCSV from this link.
To get to know how to use this script and database on your server you please read this article-
http://phpweby.com/software/ip2country

Its working fine for me.